# How can I solve $\int \left| \sum_{i=0}^{N} f_i(x) \right|^2 d x $ for complex functions $f_i$?

Tags: complex-integration

The $f_i(x)$ are complex functions and I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_i (x ) \, d x=c_i$.

How can solve this integral?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left| \sum_{i=0}^{N} f_i(x) \right|^2 d x $$

Comment: $f_i$ must be zero, because its integral is a constant. That is, the sum is 0. Integrating 0 squared is just another (complex) constant.

Comment: Which set do you integrate over? Are you integrating over the entire real line or are you perhaps finding an antiderivative? And what else do you assume about your functions? Try to give more details so that others can help.

Comment: By "solve" I think he means "evaluate".  And he is integrating over a fixed domain (so they are definite integrals).

Comment: In general, even for the case $N=1$ we cannot do this.  Even if we know $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = c$, this does not determine $v=\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2\,dx$.  You can find two functions $f$ with the same mean $c$ but not the same second moment $v$.